# Javascript files not found in ios11

Tags: cordova, uiwebview, ios11

I am using cordova to build an ios app. The app builds and works fine for ios 9 & ios 10 and the simulator works perfectly fine also. But for ios 11, it throws errors loading all the javascript files in the "scripts" folder. I don't think it's because the folder name is case sensitive. The files all exist.

See the error screenshot below that shows in Safari debugger:

[image: ios 11 error]

Any ideas? I would really appreciate any help. Again, this runs perfectly fine on ios 9 and ios 10, has issue only on 11.

Here is my script includes:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  

<!-- essential utilities -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/knockout-3.4.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.tasksq.com/api/signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- essential ui utilities -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/select2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/bootbox.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/toastr.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/knockout.validation.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/knockstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- my utilities -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/app/koBindings.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/app/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/require.js" data-main="Scripts/app/main"></script>
```

As you can probably tell, the script include in the root or the http one works, just the ones in the script folder have the issue.

Comment: Do you see any entries in the console? I have seen a similar problem starting in iOS 11 that is related to using a self-signed certificate in a web app. Maybe this is somehow related? https://www.neunbeere.de/blog/2017/12/bug-in-ios-11-safari-mobile-sometimes-not-loading-script-files-when-using-a-self-signed-certificate/